# Watch meteor collection in controller/directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-meteor

This question mostly about angular-meteor package for AngularJs 1.x

I'm trying to watch meteor collection and do some calculations when it was changed.

```
angular.module('my-app').controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$meteor', function($scope, $meteor) {
    var filter = {myfield: 10};
    $meteor.subscribe('mycollection', filter);
    $scope.mycollection = $scope.$meteorCollection(Mycollection);

    $scope.$watch('mycollection', function () {
        console.log($scope.mycollection.length)
    });
}]);
```

But it doesn't work. The watch function will be called only once when `$scope.mycollection` is empty, no matter how many times mycollection has been changed. How to watch for changes in `mycollection`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set object Equality option to true for setting deep watcher

```
$scope.$watch('mycollection', function (newVal) {
    console.log($scope.mycollection.length)
}, true); //true for deep watch
```

If you don't wanted to use deep watcher you could use shallow watcher using [**`$watchCollection`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection), Because the deep watcher will impact on if you are using deep watcher.

Comment: Thank you, it's work! But which one is better or it is equivalent?

Comment: @Deadly if you want to fire a watch on any of the property change of the `mycollection` object that might be on very deeper level then do use `$watch` with `true` option which indicates deep watch..but if you are interested in first level element then use the `$watchCollection`

Comment: @Deadly Glad to help you..Thanks :)